# Yii2, заменить ссылку "Главная" картинкой

Tags: php, html, yii2, yii

Добрый день! На странице вывожу хлебные крошко с помощью виджета Breadcrumbs, согласно дизайну текстовую ссылку на главную необходимо заменить картинкой-ссылкой на главную.

Как это можно реализовать с помощью этого виджета?

Просто в документации что-то не нашёл.

Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете расширить класс стандартного виджета, если речь о первом yii, то это класс CBreadcrumbs
если посмотреть класс, то там есть атрибут homeLink, вот стандартный код

```
/**
 * Renders the content of the portlet.
 */
public function run()
{
    if(empty($this->links))
        return;

    echo CHtml::openTag($this->tagName,$this->htmlOptions)."\n";
    $links=array();
    if($this->homeLink===null)
        $links[]=CHtml::link(Yii::t('zii','Home'),Yii::app()->homeUrl);
    elseif($this->homeLink!==false)
        $links[]=$this->homeLink;
    foreach($this->links as $label=>$url)
    {
        if(is_string($label) || is_array($url))
            $links[]=strtr($this->activeLinkTemplate,array(
                '{url}'=>CHtml::normalizeUrl($url),
                '{label}'=>$this->encodeLabel ? CHtml::encode($label) : $label,
            ));
        else
            $links[]=str_replace('{label}',$this->encodeLabel ? CHtml::encode($url) : $url,$this->inactiveLinkTemplate);
    }
    echo implode($this->separator,$links);
    echo CHtml::closeTag($this->tagName);
}
```

вам просто нужно в своем классе переопределить создание $this->homeLink

В Yii2 принцип должен быть такой же

Comment: извиняюсь, что сразу не указал, проект на Yii2

Comment: Принцип там такой же, как вариант может это вам поможет https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6106